# Update Nodejs to v5.x from v0.12.7 on Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I'm trying to put a MEAN stack app on a DigitalOcean MEAN image droplet.  I followed [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-mean-one-click-install-image) step-by-step tutorial on how to login and upload the files via Github.

That's all fine, but one of my app dependencies relies on Node v4 or greater:

```
npm WARN engine mongoose-paginate@5.0.0: wanted: {"node":">=4.0.0"} (current: {"node":"0.12.7","npm":"2.11.3"}
```

So, what I did was try to update Nodejs to the latest version, which is 5.1.0 using [this](https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_5.x) setup script.

To do that, I ran the following commands from Terminal:

```
$ curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_5.x | bash -
$ apt-get install nodejs
```

Then, I was given this message:

```
nodejs is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 95 not upgraded.
```

I know it didn't update because if I run `node -v` it says `v0.12.7`.  I even restarted the droplet, but nothing happens.

(I did all of this under root user btw)

Comment: Perhaps you could install node via NVM: http://askubuntu.com/questions/672994/how-to-install-nodejs-4-on-ubuntu-15-04-64-bit-edition

Comment: @gnerkus It worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tend to use `npm install -g n` and `n 5.4.1` or `nvm`, when I have **any** version of node installed.

On Ubuntu, if I don't have anything installed, I find it easiest to compile from source:

```
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential
git clone https://github.com/nodejs/node && cd node
./configure
make -j8 && make install
```